# System.IndexOutOfRangeException on OutBound Message Listener

Tags: community, webservices, c#, workflowoutboundmessage

I have a webservice in ASMX and I am trying to create a Listener and here is what I have in the webservice.cs file

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
class MyNotificationListener : NotificationBinding
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]

    public notificationsResponse Notifications(notifications n)
    {
        Method.SendMail("info@domain.com", "test@domain.com", "Here I am ", "I am loaded ", "", "");// This is to see if it loaded
        notificationsResponse r = new notificationsResponse();
        r.Ack = true;
        return r;
    }

}
```

in my outboun message configuration I am calling this webservice like so `http://www.domain.com/webservice.asmx/Notifications` but when I load this service I See the following:

```
`System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)`
```

In my config file I have the following

```
 `<webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
        <add name="HttpSoap" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>`
```

How do I fix this? It doesnt even load this method not even sending that email notification.

Comment: Is this related to Salesforce?

Comment: @JayantDas Yes this is the Outbound Message Listener

Comment: SFSE addresses issues specific to Salesforce platform. This seems to be a code written in C# and errors related to that. You will get more help on this on stackoverflow.

Comment: @JayantDas Thanks for letting me know, I will ask it there!